# Reload or clear data in existing form in Symfony2.1

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

We upgraded from Symfony 2.0 to 2.1. With 2.0, I used to modify the entity and reload the form like this:

```
$form->setData($entity);
```

But this is not allowed anymore with Symfony 2.1 (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3322). I get the following error:

```
You cannot change the data of a bound form
```

Is there a way to rebind the form to the entity/reload the data?

Comment: Could you please post your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could create a new instance of the form and re-bind. Seems like overkill, but it would work in a pinch.

Comment: Yeah I had tried that but it's a pain given that we have a base form and use ->remove in the controler to keep the fields we need. Still I don't think there's another way so thanks for your help

Comment: @Ben Make a `private function()` on the controller that makes the baseForm, and adds the `->remove()`s. That way it's as simple as another `$this->something()`.

Answer (score 11):

I did something that did the trick… Don't know if it's best way but…

```
public function contactAction(Request $request){
    $task = new myBundle();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('email', 'text', array('label'=>'E-mail'))
        ->add('message', 'textarea')
        ->add('newsletter', 'checkbox', array('label'=>'blabla','required'=>false))
        ->getForm();

   $cloned = clone $form;

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            [... code ...]
            $form = $cloned;
        }
    }
    return $this->render(
         'myBundle:Default:contact.html.twig',
          array('form' => $form->createView())
     );
}
```

By cloning the just instanciated form object, I can switch the «full» one by the empty one, and keep all the params.

Answer (score 8):

And the most obvious way to reset the form after a successful post. Set a "flash", redirect to the form page and display the flash:

```
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    $contact = new Contact();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //...

        $session = $this->container->get('session');
        $session->getFlashBag()->set('success', 'Your message has been sent.');

        return $this->redirect($this->get('router')->generate('contact'));
    }

    return array(
        'form'  => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

And in your twig:

```
{% if app.session.flashBag.has('success') %}
    {{ app.session.flashBag.get('success')[0] }}
{% endif %}
```